# Why I can't choose only a number as variable's name in titan graph database

Tags: variables, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I've worked with TinkerFactory.createModern & TinkerFactory.createTheCrew and I've noticed only numbers have been chosen as variables if I'm not mistaking...what I mean is that by "g.V(1)" you can reach Vertex number 1 so I want to do the same but i get the error shown in the picture.
for instance, I want to reach 'V[5]' by typing "g.V(5)"
[This is the Picture of the error that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHovc.jpg)

Comment: The Gremlin shell is a groovy shell. For identifiers the regular [Groovy syntax](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html) rules apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers you refer to in `g.V(1)` are the ids which are automatically assigned to each vertex. So when you say `g.V(1)` you are asking for the vertex with ID 1. Which is not necessarily the first vertex. Titan uses quite large numbers for example

The error you are having is a different issue though. Variables **cannot** start with number. They must start with a letter. So do this instead:

```
v1 = graph.addVertex('name', 'something');
```

Comment: I get it. something strange happened for me! when I added a vertex by "graph.addVertex('name','Something')" the output was V[0] as usual. I tried "g.V(0)" but I get error. I saved my graph and opened it again and run exactly "g.V(0)" and it worked!!! the output was V[0]. I don't understand!

Comment: That appears to be a bug in the gremlin terminal. It is interpreting your `0` as an integer when it should be a long. If you try this `g.V("0".toLong())` it works. This is most likely a bug in the terminal though.

Comment: It's not a bug. That the default TinkerGraph id manager at work. http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_configuration_2